# How To Replace a String Consists of DateTime with empty String?

Tags: c#, regex, datetime, replace

How to replace a string for example

```
LD1091158 LD1091158 LD1091158 ScreenLysP - :10/11/2013 3:30:46 PM  1 91 / ABDLys2HB+ LD1091159 LD1091159 LD1091159 ScreenLysP - ABDLys2HA+
```

the above one is a string. In this i want to replace **10/11/2013 3:30:46 PM** this one to empty string.
 I used Regex for this one but it does not work.

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d\d:\d\d:\d\d [AP]M", "");
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\d\d` matches 2 digits. Use `\d{1,2}` or `\d\d?` to match 1 or 2 digits.

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d\d:\d\d [AP]M", "");
//                                         ^^^^^^^
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/k0JE8a).

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regex

```
\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}\s\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s[AP]M
```

[image]

Points you missed

1. To escape space, you need `\s`
2. To escape `/`, you need `\/`

### **Updates:**

I tried this and it works for me

```
string s = "LD1091158 LD1091158 LD1091158 ScreenLysP - :10/11/2013 3:30:46 PM  1 91 / ABDLys2HB+ LD1091159 LD1091159 LD1091159 ScreenLysP - ABDLys2HA+ ";
string ss = Regex.Replace(s, @"\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}\s\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s[AP]M", "");
Console.WriteLine(ss);
```

**Output:**

> LD1091158 LD1091158 LD1091158 ScreenLysP - :  1 91 /
>   ABDLys2HB+ LD1091159 LD1091 159 LD1091159 ScreenLysP - ABDLys2HA+

Comment: You don't need to escape `/`.